# How to integrate jQuery template into React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am developing a React App, and have bought a template that is using HTML, CSS, and jQuery. It just works for most of the stuffs, but when it comes to some `$(document).ready` function, as in React, it was just a state change instead of page change, the `ready` event will not be triggered and cannot be triggered manually by `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('ready'))` as I tried.

What should I do to integrate it into my app? It will be a very time consuming task to rewrite all those things into react lifecycle event.

FYI, the function I am getting trouble is the following code, that was making the website responsive and show the menu in a right layout, classifying device's size by calculating the windows' width. The current solution for me is to show an alert to the user to remind user to refresh when they are not getting the right layout, but it was way too idiot:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var totalWidth = $(window).width(),
        layout = $('.layout').css("font-family"),
        secondary_sidebar_width = 200;


    // ---------------------------------
    // 1. Handheld devices menu toggle
    // ---------------------------------
    $(".left-toggle-switch").hammer().on("click touchstart", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("body").hasClass("left-aside-toggle")) {
            $("body").removeClass("left-aside-toggle");
        } else {
            $("body").addClass("left-aside-toggle");
        }
    });

    function AsideHeight() {
        var TopBarHeight = $('.main-nav').height(),
            calc_wh = wh - TopBarHeight,
            menuMargin = $('header').outerHeight(),
            containerMargin = $('.main-nav').outerHeight(),
            menuHeight = wh - menuMargin;

        $(window).resize(function() {
            if($(window).width() < 801) {
                $(".menu").css({
                    "height": wh + "px"
                });
                $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                $(".user-profile").load("menus/sidebar-user-profile.html");
                $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                $('.left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                    height: calc_wh + 50,
                    width: "250px"
                    }).mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                });

                if($(window).width() == 800) {
                    $(".container-sidebar").css({
                        "height": "100%",
                        "width": "200px",
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "float": "left"
                    });

                    $('.secondary-sidebar').slimscroll({
                        height: calc_wh,
                        width: "200px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });

                    $(".container-aside").css({
                        "width": totalWidth - secondary_sidebar_width,
                        "margin-left": secondary_sidebar_width,
                        "float": "left"
                    });
                }
            }

            else if(($(window).width() >= 1024)){

                // ---------------------------------
                // 2. Material menu
                // ---------------------------------
                if(layout == "material"){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" sidebar");
                    $(".user-profile").load("menus/sidebar-user-profile.html");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                    $(".sidebar").css({
                        "height": menuHeight ,
                        "top": menuMargin
                    });
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $('.sidebar .left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 12,
                        width: "220px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 220;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 3. Dropdown menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'dropdown'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" dd");
                    $(".menu").css('top', menuMargin);
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/dropdown.html");
                    var sidebar_width = 0;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 4. Dropdown label menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'dropdown_label'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" dd");
                    $(".menu").css('top', menuMargin);
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/dropdown.html");
                    var sidebar_width = 0;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 5. Megamenu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'megamenu'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" megamenu");
                    $(".menu").css('top', menuMargin);
                    $("ul.main-menu").css('top', menuMargin);
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/megamenu.html");
                    var sidebar_width = 0;

                    $(function () {
                        menuOpen();
                    });
                    function menuOpen() {
                        $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                            if ($(window).width() > 750) {
                                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).show('slow');
                            }
                        });
                        $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                            if ($(window).width() > 750) {
                                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).hide('slow');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 6. Iconic menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'iconic'){
                    $("body").addClass(" iconic-view");
                    $(".menu").addClass(" iconic-leftbar");
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".iconic-leftbar").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".user-profile").load("menus/sidebar-user-profile.html");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/iconic.html");
                    $('ul.sidemenu-sub').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 10,
                        width: "200px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 60;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 7. Sidebar menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'sidebar'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" leftmenu");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".leftmenu").css({
                        "height": menuHeight +1,
                        "top": menuMargin
                    });
                    $('.leftmenu .left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 11,
                        width: "220px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 220;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 8. Boxed menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'boxed'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" leftmenu");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".leftmenu").css({
                        "height": menuHeight +1,
                        "top": menuMargin
                    });
                    $('.leftmenu .left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 11,
                        width: "200px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 200;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 9. Iconbar menu
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == 'iconbar'){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" leftmenu");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".leftmenu").css({
                        "height": menuHeight +1,
                        "top": menuMargin
                    });
                    $('.leftmenu .left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 11,
                        width: "160px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 200;
                }


                // ---------------------------------
                // 10. Default menu (material)
                // ---------------------------------
                else if(layout == ''){
                    $(".menu").addClass(" leftmenu");
                    $(".menu-container").load("menus/material-sidebar.html");
                    $(".main-container").css('margin-top', containerMargin);
                    $(".leftmenu").css({
                        "height": menuHeight +1,
                        "top": menuMargin
                    });
                    $('.leftmenu .left-aside-container').slimscroll({
                        height: menuHeight + 11,
                        width: "200px"
                        }).mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                    });
                    var sidebar_width = 200;
                }

                $(".container-sidebar").css({
                    "height": "100%",
                    "width": "200px",
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "float": "left"
                });

                $('.secondary-sidebar').slimscroll({
                    height: calc_wh,
                    width: "200px"
                    }).mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).next('.slimScrollBar');
                });

                $(".container-aside").css({
                    "width": totalWidth - secondary_sidebar_width - sidebar_width,
                    "margin-left": secondary_sidebar_width,
                    "float": "left"
                });
            }
        }).resize();
    }
    AsideHeight();
});
```

**Updated**

I am using `create-react-app` to generate the structure, I added the script in `public/index.html` (layouts.js):

```
<!-- Global scripts -->
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/jquery/jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/hammer/hammerjs.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/hammer/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/forms/uniform.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/app/layouts.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/js/core/app/core.js"></script>
<!-- /Global scripts -->
```

Thanks for reading and any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 main solution and both depends on how your scaffolding changes are implemented:

**Case #1 - Static scaffolding embedding React app**
If your scaffolding is served through your static index.html which **contains** your react app, you can use document.ready directly on the document, loaded as standalone script.

**Case #2 - Rect app including your jquery-managed scaffolding**
In case your jquery-managed scaffolding is loaded in a react component you can execute the code in `componentDidMount` lifecycle callback but remember to eventually remove the listener in `componentWillUnmount` callback in order to avoid both multiple listener to be added or event callback acting on elements no more available in the DOM.

The situation may be bit more complex or simpler depending on the complexity of your React app.

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct or not, but I guess my case is case #1, which I added the script in index.html. I have updated the coding reference.

Comment: May I have some more details about the solution? I have tried several way to trigger the change with no luck, and your solution may save my life!

Comment: The solution applied strongly depends on your app structure/scaffolding, you should reproduce the issue in a mini application in order to provide further details.
Try to add the 2 main listener ($(".left-toggle-switch").hammer().on() and $(window).resize()) in componentDidMount and remove the listener ($(window).off("resize") and $(".left-toggle-switch").hammer().off("click touchstart") in componentWillUnmount of your app.js main entry lifecycle